# Does usermod and chage lock the accounts in a similar way?

Tags: linux, rhel, users

Is there any difference in using the two commands if you want to lock and expire the account? or does one of them allow for login through SSH?

```
usermod -L -e 0 user1
chage -E 0 user1
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `usermod` and `chage` affect `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`. Neither one stops ssh public key authentication. `chmod 000 $USER/.ssh` will prevent ssh login.

Comment: What is the significance of locking an account vs. expiring it?

Comment: Expiring an account leaves open the possibility of the user re-enabling her account by changing her password

Comment: I used `chage -E 0 user1` and then tried to login as user1 and it gave me authentication failure. I am not sure how user1 can change it's password.

Comment: Could `user1` login via ssh, using public key encryption, both before and after the `chage -E 0 user1`? Same with ssh using password authentication? If one logs in via `login`, and your password has expired, you'll be prompted. Not so with most display manager logins.

Comment: So I experimented on it. I used `usermod  -L user1` to lock the account. I checked `/etc/shadow` and there was an `!` before the password. Just locking it prevented SSH password based authentication but not key based. When I expired the account without locking it using `usermod -e 1 user1`, it blocked both SSH password and keybased authentication. Further setting shell to `/sbin/nologin` on an unlocked and unexpired account prevented SSH key-based login.